# How to implement Database Query and Write in Android allowing multi process access

Tags: realm

I tried to use a Singleton MessageStorage Class to access Realm Database, which turns out to be an incorrect way. For lacking of Multiprocess support, I write a record in Service Process(process: background),but fail to query it in Activity Process, for it may refer to the multi-process support issue in Realm-java.

So I wonder how to implement the database access in such situation which could guarantee multi-process safe. I am thinking about access realm db only in my background service, but there's still some problems about sending request to the service and geting the response in the activity. Is there any examples???

THX

Comment: *but there's still some problems about sending request to the service and geting the response in the activity* what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I could not use anything like EventBus/Otto to do the communications, only solution I could find is to use Messenger+Handler and Broadcast to request and get response from my background service. Is that a reasonable way or there is a more convenient method?

Comment: Before Realm Java support multi processes (track this PR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1300), I think you have to pick one Android way to do it. Messenger+Handler and Broadcast (also there are others) are both fine but it really depends on what do you need. Just try them and use one fits your requirements.